# How Select Back & Next element with CSS in html Code

Tags: html, css

i have this Html Code:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

ex : When **`<li>4</li>`** Mouse is Hover > **`<li>3</li>`** & **`<li>5</li>`** Set Style...

ex : When **`<li>2</li>`** Mouse is Hover . **`<li>1</li>`** & **`<li>3</li>`** Set Style...

can do this without using Jquery? Thnaks

Comment: Without jQuery, yes - but you'd still need Javascript for the previous-sibling part. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might have cracked this in pure CSS... it does contain a bit of a hack to reverse the natural `z-index` which I don't like, but it sorts things out.

The theory is this: you set a fixed height for the `li` and give it a `border-top-width` of the same value. You can then "stack" the list items on top of one and other so that the top border can "pretend" to be the background for the item above.

Enough gassing let's show the code...

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/Awjmp/

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding:0;
}
ul {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* stop the first item's border bursting the container */
}
li {
    height: 20px;
    border-top-width: 20px;
    /* li.height */
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #eee;
    /* ul.background-color */
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -20px;
    /* -li.height */
}
li:hover {
    background-color: red;
    /* "current" colour */
    border-top-color: yellow;
    /* "previous" colour */
}
li:hover + li {
    background-color: lime;
    /* "next" colour */
}
/* HACK... reverse the natural z-index */
 li:nth-child(9) {
    z-index: 1
}
li:nth-child(8) {
    z-index: 2
}
li:nth-child(7) {
    z-index: 3
}
li:nth-child(6) {
    z-index: 4
}
li:nth-child(5) {
    z-index: 5
}
li:nth-child(4) {
    z-index: 6
}
li:nth-child(3) {
    z-index: 7
}
li:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 8
}
li:nth-child(1) {
    z-index: 9
}
```

Comment: great, I was trying something similar to this with `:before` and `:after` but it wasn't quite working.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `+` selector to select the next element:

```
li:hover + li {
    background-color: red;
}
```

There is not a selector for the previous element.

Edit: here is a way to do it similar to [gvee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210931/how-select-back-next-element-with-css-in-html-code/18211080#18217295).

Answer (score 0):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/q6QS5/

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
li:hover
{
    background-color: red;
}

li:hover + li
{
    background-color: lime;
}

.previous
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

### JQuery

This is needed to get the "previous" item highlighted

```
$('li').hover(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('previous');
});
```

Comment: thanks . but my goal is make this with out Jquery . nothing this work.

Comment: As mentioned by others: the "previous" item highlight is not possible without a little bit of JavaScript